# Overwrite existing file in a specific Google Drive folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I need the `var file = dir.createFile(blob).setContent('Stores_Month.pdf');` to every time, overwrite the existing **Stores_Month.pdf** file in the specified Google Drive folder.

```
function runCBUEBUquarterly() {

  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Data_Stores_Quarter.csv").next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Data_Month');
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);


 /* Highlight all sort range and sort by AS - Okanagan */ 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Stores_Month');
  var range = sheet.getRange("A5:AS10");

 // Sorts by the values in column (AS)
  range.sort({column: 45, ascending: false});


   /* Highlight all sort range and sort by AS - LM & Whistler */ 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Stores_Month');
  var range = sheet.getRange("A13:AS24");

 // Sorts by the values in column (AS)
  range.sort({column: 45, ascending: false});


 /* Save as PDF to Google Drive */ 
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Stores_Month');

  var url = ss.getUrl();

  //remove the trailing 'edit' from the url
  url = url.replace(/edit$/,'');

  //additional parameters for exporting the sheet as a pdf
  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + //export as pdf
  //below parameters are optional...
  '&size=letter' + //paper size
  '&portrait=false' + //orientation, false for landscape
  '&fitw=false' + //fit to width, false for actual size
  '&pagenumbers=true' + //fit to width, false for actual size    
  '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + //hide optional headers and footers
  '&gridlines=false' + //hide gridlines
  '&fzr=true' + //do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  '&gid=' + sheet.getSheetId(); //the sheet's Id

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
      }
    });

  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(sheet.getName() + '.pdf');

  //from here you should be able to use and manipulate the blob to send and email or create a file per usual.
  //In this example, I save the pdf to drive



  var dir = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('CBU & EBU - Quarterly Tracker').next();
  var file = dir.createFile(blob).setContent('Stores_Month.pdf');

}
```

Comment: If it helps, here's a blog post on this but I can't seem to make it work.
https://ctrlq.org/docs/20472-overwrite-existing-files-in-google-drive as `      Drive.Files.update({` seems to be depreciated or the one that's causing issues.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to use something like the following code.  I haven't tested it, but try it out, and see what happens:

```
var dir, file, newContent;

//dir = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('CBU & EBU - Quarterly Tracker').next();
dir = DriveApp.getFolderById('put the folder ID here');//Get folder by ID

file = dir.getFilesByName('Stores_Month.pdf').next();

if (file) {//There is an existing file by that name
  newContent = blob.getDataAsString();
  Logger.log('blob: ' + blob);
  Logger.log('blob.getDataAsString(): ' + blob.getDataAsString());

  file.setContent(newContent);//The new content must be a string
} else {//no file by that name was found
  file = dir.createFile(blob).setName('Stores_Month.pdf');
}
```

Comment: It seems the PDF file is now outputting blank 2 pages. Any suggestions?

Comment: I wonder if there is anything in the `blob`  I added a couple of `Logger.log()` lines to the code to check the blob.  Run the code, and then VIEW the LOGS, and see what is being printed to the log for the blob.

Comment: It's a bunch of gibberish with question mark symbols in the Log. Too large to paste here. https://pastebin.com/ndS5PgNZ

Comment: Okay, well, there is some content in the blob instead of being empty.  Try "hard coding" some content for the new content, like: `newContent = "This is a test."` and comment out `newContent = blob.getDataAsString();` and see what happens.  See if the content gets overwritten with the hard coded content.

Comment: The output then is a single page "This is a test."

Comment: Seems a filetype is not being determined which is why the createFile can't create properly?

Comment: The line for `createFile` should never run.  You already created that file.  The line for `createFile` is in the `else` block of the "if/else" statement.  That part of the code will never run, unless you deleted the file.  When the code finds the file, it runs the code in the "if" "block."

Comment: No, I am still using existing code it seems to overwrite with blank data still.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is.  Obviously `file.setContent(newContent);` will overwrite content in an existing file.  I'm wondering if the file type or the format of the content is the problem.

Comment: Well I've exported the pdf normally with the exclusion of your code and it opens fine with data in it. After using your code, the pdf exports to the 2 pages but with blank format. I'll share you the sheet so you can test yourself